# What does -> after a function prototype mean?

Tags: c++, c++11

What is happening in this code? Is so confusing.

```
#include <utility>

struct check
{
   template <typename T>
   auto foo() -> decltype(std::declval<T>().value, void())
   {
      static_assert(T{}.value == 10, "Incorrect value");
   }
} var;

int main()
{
   struct apple
   {
      int value{10};
   };

   var.foo<apple>();
}
```

Specifically the part where it has `->` and everything after that.

Comment: The -> is a trailing return type. `declval` makes an instance of the class. `decltype` finds the type of a compile-time expression. `static_assert` is a compile-time assert. Time to piece them together :)

Comment: Vague title is not going to be useful to others with the same question.

Comment: @RiaD: While that title edit is more helpful, it's still inaccurate - he's asking about a specific-use, it seems.

Comment: Made an edit to the title suggesting "What does -> after a function prototype mean?".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's go through bit by bit.

```
auto foo() -> decltype(std::declval<T>().value, void())
```

This is a trailing return type. It's allowed to use parameters, but here that isn't necessary. I'd guess it's written like that to be clearer. `decltype` finds the type of the expression inside, but that expression is not actually evaluated. `std::declval` is used for creating an instance of the type passed to it. The comma operator is used here to make the overall return type `void`, since the comma operator evaluates the left side, throws it away, evaluates the right side, and returns that.

The first part creates a sort of SFINAE (though I've never seen it used like this). For example, if you had an overload of `foo` that did the same with `value2` instead of `value`, there would be no ambiguity of which to call. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ecb6724137256608d47ef79f2ac34e6d-8a676986784bd3a58ce3ec015645a41f) for what I mean. Compare it to [this one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1f82f36715bcf739a2847a8f38a68e1f-8a676986784bd3a58ce3ec015645a41f), which just has a return type of `void` and causes errors.

```
static_assert(T{}.value == 10, "Incorrect value");
```

This line makes sure a value-initialized instance of `T` has its `value` member have a value of 10. If it doesn't, a compiler error with that text is generated.

```
} var;
```

This is just a global object of that class to use.

```
struct apple
{
   int value{10};
};
```

This is a sample class to test it with. It has a `value` member and that member is 10 in a value-initialized instance (default-initialized as well).

```
var.foo<apple>();
```

This just calls the function.

Comment: When I do `struct grape {}; var.foo<grape>();` it gives me an error. How can I make it silently fail?

Comment: @MemyselfandI, You need to have a version of `foo` that works with structures like grape. The thing is that you have to make sure calling it with `apple` is not ambiguous. I'll try to prepare an example.

Comment: @MemyselfandI, With many thanks to Xeo, [here you go](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=200ce7dd4c270d3bfdea6df8628f6e4e-8a676986784bd3a58ce3ec015645a41f). That's one where you can implement `foo` based on whether the type has a `value` data member or not.